# How to avoid adding the same data model that has the same primary key in realm database?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

[image]

I have one to many relationship between two models, `Product` and `WishList` like the code below

```
class Product : Object {

    @objc dynamic var productID : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var unitPrice: Double = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var imagePath : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var quantity = 0
    @objc dynamic var hasBeenAddedToWishList : Bool = false
    var parentCategory = LinkingObjects(fromType: WishList.self, property: "products")

    convenience init(productID : String, name: String, unitPrice: Double, imagePath: String, quantity: Int = 1, hasBeenAddedToWishList: Bool = false) {
        self.init()

        self.productID = productID
        self.name = name
        self.unitPrice = unitPrice
        self.imagePath = imagePath
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.hasBeenAddedToWishList = hasBeenAddedToWishList
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "productID"
    }

}
```

and WishList:

```
class WishList : Object {
    @objc dynamic var userID: String = ""
    var products = List<Product>()
}
```

I try to add or remove product to WishList using the code below when love button in the image above is pressed :

```
    // 1. get the wishlist based on UserID

    let allWishList = realm.objects(WishList.self)
    let theWishList = allWishList.filter("userID CONTAINS[cd] %@", userID).first

    guard let userWishList = theWishList else {return}


    // 2. modify Wishlist data in Realm.

    if loveIconHasBeenFilled {

       guard let index = userWishList.products.index(where: {$0.productID == selectedProduct.productID}) else {return}

       do {
        // remove data from realm database            

          try realm.write {
            userWishList.products.remove(at: index)
          }

        } catch {
          // error Handling
        }



    } else {

      do {

         // add product to wishlist model in realm database

         try realm.write {
            userWishList.products.append(selectedProduct)
         }

      } catch {
        // error Handling
      }


   }
```

and here is the data in Realm Browser
[image]

[image]

and the problem is ....

when I run the app for the first time, I can add, and then remove, and then add the product again to the wishlist, and the number of product in the realm database still be the same (all have unique productID)

but when I restart the app, and try to click that love button to add the product to wishlist again, it throws an error

> 'RLMException', reason: 'Attempting to create an object of type
>   'Product' with an existing primary key value 'a'

this error is triggered because of this line of code `userWishList.products.append(selectedProduct)` , when adding the product to `WishList`, it automatically adds `Product` in the realm database. so because I keep adding the same product that has the same productID (primary key) it will throw that error.

so, my question is, how to avoid addition in `Product` if it has the same productID (primary key), it is better if i can just update the product in realm database when adding the product to the wishlist using this line of code: `userWishList.products.append(selectedProduct)`

Comment: maybe you can consider creating another realm object to save the relation between Product and WishList

Answer (score 0):

You could check the property `hasBeenAddedToWishList` of the selected product and only add it if the property is false.

```
 if loveIconHasBeenFilled {
   //your logic to remove already added products

} else if !selectedProduct.hasBeenAddedToWishList { //<--- check if the product already exists in wishlist if not you add it

  do {

     // add product to wishlist model in realm database

     try realm.write {
        userWishList.products.append(selectedProduct)
     }

  } catch {
    // error Handling
  }
```

}